# Why does the 'use' tag size not match the svg element it references?

Tags: html, css, svg

Looking at the following code snippet, I would expect the svg element referenced by "use" to be constrained within a 100px wide and 100px tall box:

```css
body {
background: blue;
}

.svgautohide {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div style="height:100px;background:red">
  <svg><use xlink:href="#icontest"></use></svg>
</div>

<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="svgautohide">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icontest">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

</body>
```

However, this is not what I'm seeing, as the screenshot below illustrates:

[image]

This doesn't appear to be a browser bug, as the same behaviour was replicated across Firefox, Edge and Chrome. Can anyone help explain why the "use" box is a different size to the svg? Also, can anything be done to override this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: you didn't specify any viewbox or size for the SVG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a width and height for the referencing `<svg>`.

Both `<svg>` elements and `<symbol>`/`<use>`/ combinations provide a mechanism for fitting one area inside another:

- For `<svg>`, the `viewBox` area is fitted inside the box defined by `width` and `height`.
- For `<use>`, the `viewBox` area defined for the `<symbol>` is fitted inside the box defined by `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` of the `<use>`.

For both, if no `viewBox` is given, content remains at original size. A missing `x` or `y` defaults to 0. A missing `width` or `height` defaults to 100%. Percentages are defined in relation to the viewport, that is the size of the viewBox of the next outer `<svg>` (or the size of the svg itself, if it is missing).

In contrast, if the `<svg>` is the outermost in a HTML page, `width` and `height` are presentation attributes with a default value of `auto`. They are resolved within the CSS cascade and following its [rules for inline-block elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height). If finding a concrete size fails, the default object size comes out at 300px * 150px:

> Otherwise, if `height` has a computed value of `auto`, but none of the conditions above are met, then the used value of `height` must be set to the height of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio, has a height not greater than 150px, and has a width not greater than the device width.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I appreciate it.